# Back-end tests with elasticsearch fails without setTimeout

Tags: elasticsearch, mocha.js, supertest

I am writing tests for back-end which uses MongoDB and Elasticsearch. The problem is that without wrapping test with `setTimeout` test fails, and it looks like elasticsearch can't index mock data into db before test. Here is the code:

```
let elasticSearch = require('elasticsearch');
let elasticClient = new elasticSearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200'
});
let app = require('./dist/app'); //path to my application
let supertest = require('supertest');

before((done) => {
  elasticClient.index(elasticMockData, function() {
    done();
  });
});

beforeEach(() => {
  request = supertest(app);
});

it('should get data from elastic', () => {
  setTimeout(() => { // if I comment this timeout, test will fail
    request.get('/api/elastic')
           .end((err, res) => {
             expect(res.body.hits.hits.length).not.to.equal(0);
           })
  }, 1000); // if I comment this timeout, test will fail
});
```

I think you will agree that timeout is not an elegant and nice solution, which slows every test to 1 second or more. Maybe, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, maybe it will be useful for someone.
According to [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-index):

> By default, the document will be available for get() actions immediately, but will only be available for searching after an index refresh (which can happen automatically or manually).

So, in this case, `done()` should be called within another callback function:

```
before((done) => {
  elasticClient.index(elasticMockData, function() {
     elasticClient.indices.refresh(function (err: any, res: any) {
        if (err) {
          return;
        }
        done();
     });
  });
});
```